# Multiple line charts using multiple values of drop down in Plotly in R

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have a dataframe df with one column with 160 ids.

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1:10),s1=c(1:10),s2=c(11:20),s3=c(6:15))
```

I am passing ID variable to a drop down menu in R shiny with option for selecting multiple values. Below is the code for it:

```
ui <-  shinyUI(fluidPage(mainPanel(
  selectInput("columns1","Select ID:",df$id,multiple = TRUE), plotlyOutput("TestChart")
)))
```

Now I can choose a (one) value from the dropdown and I can create a plotly line chart where x axis is number of columns excluding ID column ( s1,s2,s3) and y axis is the value of these columns.Below is the code for that:

```
server <- function(input, output){

output$TestChart<-renderPlotly({

  df1<-as.data.frame(t(df[df$id== input$columns1 ,]))
  df1<-as.data.frame(df1[-1,])
  colnames(df1)[1]<-"AB"

  plot_ly(df1,
          x = 1:3,
          y = ~AB,
          color =  list( 'rgba(55, 128, 191, 0.7)'))  %>%
add_lines()%>%
layout(title ="score",

       xaxis = list(title = "AB"),
       yaxis = list(title = "Frequency"))

})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

With above code, I can select any one value from dropdown and my plotly graph will change accordingly.

**Problem**

I now want to select multiple values from my dropdown list and want all the points plotted simultaneously. So, for example if I select 3 ID's I should get 1 graphs with every ID in the same chart.

Comment: Have you tried `selectizeInput()`? https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html

Comment: I am not sure if it will help me, as multiple selection is not a problem. Selection is after getting multiple values, how to pass them and draw lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's easiest to just pass the id as the color variable:

```
df <- data.frame(id=as.character(c(1:10)),s1=c(1:10),s2=c(11:20),s3=c(6:15))
df1 <- df %>%
  gather("key", "value", 2:4) %>%
  filter(id %in% input$columns1)

plot_ly(df1,
        x = ~key,
        y = ~value,
        color = ~id
        )  %>%
  add_lines()%>%
  layout(title ="score",

         xaxis = list(title = "AB"),
         yaxis = list(title = "Frequency"))
```